# Can I override a class constructor argument name to reuse it as a public property?

Tags: scala

I need something like this:

```
class MyClass(a: String = "", b: String = "") {
  def a = this.a
  def b = if(this.b.isEmpty) this.a else this.b
}
```

can I reuse names of the constructor arguments some way? I need this because I want to use named arguments in constructor calls and still customize the output of the same-named properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use other names in the primary constructor and the names you want in an auxiliary one:

```
class MyClass private(_a: String, _b: String, _c: Any) { // _c is a dummy
  def this(a: String = "", b: String = "") = this(a, b, null)
  def a = _a
  def b = if(_b.isEmpty) _a else _b
}
```

Comment: what purpose does _c serve? and why do you need an extra variable for a?

Comment: @SeanNilan If `_c` is removed, both constructors would have the same signature and it would be a compilation error.

Comment: then why not just use default constructors as shown in the example?

Comment: @SeanNilan The point of the question is that example doesn't actually work: `this.a` and `this.b` in body of the class refer to the methods instead of the constructor parameters, so it gives an infinite loop.